# CSS Bug - Border problems on body element with horizontal scroll

Tags: html, css

This CSS issue happens on ANY web page (you can even reproduce the CSS bug using this page, or even on Google as an example).

When the "window width" is less then the "body width", the "body width" ceases to be correct. This seems to be **consistent across browsers**. I found this to be the issue in Firefox 3.6, Firefox 8 and IE.

Steps to reproduce issue:

1. Resize your browser window so that the horizontal scrollbar appears on browser
2. Now change CSS to add the border on the **body** element using firebug or whichever tool you prefer. For example: `border: 1px solid red;`
3. Now scroll your scrollbar to the right, you will notice that the the right border is on the border of window-width rather then body as expected

Is there any way to fix this problem?

Comment: That question should go to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: @CodeBrickie: I think he is using SO as an example, not because he wants to fix that. Its a prefectly valid HTML/CSS question.

Comment: @user1045380: Your title of this question is very undescriptive. You should probably change it to something more like "border problems on body element with horizontal scrollbars" that actually lets people know what the problem is at a glance. Its not actually anythign to do with fixing StackOverflow...

Comment: the only reason it might seem vague is that this website forum didnt allow me to post images. Did you try the steps? Were you able to reproduce issue? Let me know if you can reproduce it and I can help with it. How is the issue already closed when no one has answered it yet? The only question I have is how to fix the website so that body width is actually body width. The issue exists even with this website like I said earlier.

Comment: Why are people concentrating on the title of the issue rather then actual issue? The problem does exist on stackoverflow.com and it is an html issue. Did changing the title of issue help resolve it or fix it on the stackoverflow.com? Neither the issue is resolved nor stackoverflow website is fixed. There are 2 issues presented in my question : fixing stackoverflow website and the actual html issue.

Comment: The issue exists in this site, but it doesn't mean it's an issue with this site. It's just an issue with how browsers render web pages in general.